# yarn pnp fallback to default require

Tags: node.js, node-modules, yarnpkg, yarnpkg-v3

I'm writing some unit tests to check if `my-module` loads correctly a user-land module `external-module`:

```
const myMod = require('my-module')

myMod( { load: 'external-module' } )
```

Right now I'm having the error:

```
Your application tried to access transport, but it isn't declared in your dependencies; this makes the require call ambiguous and unsound.  Required package: transport Required by: /Users/mspigolon/workspace/pino/test/  Require stack: - /Users/mspigolon/workspace/pino/test/transport.test.js
```

This is loud and clear because of the test that creates at runtime the dependency in the `node_modules` folder and it is not processed by `yarn` during the installation phase.

```
  await symlink(
    join(__dirname, 'fixtures', 'transport'),
    join(__dirname, '..', 'node_modules', 'transport')
  )
```

I cannot find a way to say to `yarn@3.0.1` to do the fallback to the filesystem.

I read about the [PnPApi](https://yarnpkg.com/advanced/pnpapi) but I did not figure out how to use them to load this dependency created at runtime. Could you help me? Is it the right choice or do you see a better way?

I have tried the [pnpIgnorePatterns](https://yarnpkg.com/configuration/yarnrc#pnpIgnorePatterns) option too, but it ignore the whole file, not just one single `require`

Another solution would be to publish the `test-transport-module` and install it in my opinion, but I would avoid it.

My `yarnrc` is quite straightforward:

```
yarnPath: ".yarn/releases/yarn-berry.cjs"
nodeLinker: pnp
pnpMode: loose
```

Do you have any tips?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best solution is to install the dependency within the [`link:` protocol](https://yarnpkg.com/features/protocols)

```
yarn add --dev transport@link:./test/fixtures/transport
```